# Easy way to set javascript object multilevel property?

Tags: javascript, json, object, key-value

I am trying to create a javascript object like

```
var allUserExpiry={};
allUserExpiry[aData.userId][aData.courseId][aData.uscId] = aData;
```

But I am getting an error like `allUserExpiry[aData.userId]` undefined.

Is there a way, whereby I can set multi-level JS-Object keys? or is it important that I should go by doing `allUserExpiry[aData.userId]={}`, then `allUserExpiry[aData.userId][aData.courseId]={}` ?

Please let me know if there are any utility functions available for the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is no way to set "multilevel keys". You need to initialize each object before trying to add properties to it.

```
var allUserExpiry = {};
allUserExpiry[aData.userId] = {}
allUserExpiry[aData.userId][aData.courseId] = {}
allUserExpiry[aData.userId][aData.courseId][aData.uscId] = aData;
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Computed property names from ES6, it is possible to do:

```
var allUserExpiry = {
    [aData.userId] = {
        [aData.courseId]: {
            [aData.uscId]: aData
        }
    }
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Answer (score 5):

I have a pretty hacky but short way of doing it in IE9+ as well as real browsers.

Given `var path = 'aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.eee';` where `path` is what your intending to make into an object and `var result = {};` will will create the object `{aaa: {bbb: {ccc: {ddd: {eee: {}}}}}`

```
result = {}
path.split('.').reduce(function(prev, e) {
    var newObj = {};
    prev[e] = newObj;
    return newObj;
}, result);
```

will store the object in `result`.

#### How it works:

- `split('.')` converts the input into `['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']`
- `reduce(function (...) {...}, result)` runs through the array created by `split`, and for each entry will pass along a returned value to the next one. In our case we pass the new object through after adding the new object to the old one. This creates a chain of objects. `reduce` returns the last object you return inside of it, so we have to defined `result` beforehand.

This relies on using references so it won't be immediately clear how it works if you're expecting your code to be maintained by anyone else and should probably be avoided to be honest, but it works at least.

Comment: maybe it's too late to ask this but shouldn't it be newObj = prev[e]; instead of prev[e] = newObj; ?

Answer (score 5):

Simply use loadash,

```
let object = {};
let property = "a.b.c";
let value = 1;
_.set(object, property, value); // sets property based on path
let value = _.get(object, property, default); // gets property based on path
```

Comment: Should be the response !

Answer (score 4):

Or you can do it:

```
function setByPath(obj, path, value) {
    var parts = path.split('.');
    var o = obj;
    if (parts.length > 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i < parts.length - 1; i++) {
          if (!o[parts[i]])
              o[parts[i]] = {};
          o = o[parts[i]];
      }
    }

    o[parts[parts.length - 1]] = value;
}
```

And use:

```
setByPath(obj, 'path.path2.path', someValue);
```

This approach has many weak places, but for fun... :)

Comment: Can I ask what is wrong with this approach, what is the weak part in it?

Comment: @user3034931, sure, it is bad for code analysis (and code maintaining) and code minification (when proprties rename is used, cause this string will not be changed).

Comment: This is not "Easy way".

Comment: @IgorParra, haha, please don't forget to put same comment to all answers for the question :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just do this?

```
var allUserExpiry={};
allUserExpiry[aData.userId] = {aData.courseId: {aData.uscId: aData}};
```

Comment: Answers tend to be far more helpful with some explanation of how they work and why, to go along with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following to create the initial structure:

```
var x = function(obj, keys) {
    if (!obj) return;

    var i, t;
    for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        if (!t) {
            t = obj[keys[i]] = {};
        } else {
            t[keys[i]] = {};
            t = t[keys[i]];
        }
    }
};

var a = {}; 
x(a, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach without strings or array as argument.

```
function fillObject() {
  var o = arguments[0];
  for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length-1; i++) {
    if(!o.hasOwnProperty(arguments[i])) {
      o[arguments[i]] = {};
    }
    if(i < arguments.length-2) {
      o = o[arguments[i]];
    }else {
      o[arguments[i]] = arguments[i+1]
    }
  }
}

var myObj = {"foo":{}};

fillObject(myObj,"back","to","the","future",2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
// {"foo":{},"back":{"to":{"the":{"future":2}}}}
```

But I wouldn't use it :-) It's just for fun. 
Because I don't like too much intelligent algorithm. (If it was in this category)

Answer (score 1):

Using lodash you can do this easily **(node exists and empty check for that node)**..

```
var lodash = require('lodash-contrib');

function invalidateRequest(obj, param) {
    var valid = true;

    param.forEach(function(val) {
        if(!lodash.hasPath(obj, val)) {
            valid = false;
        } else {
            if(lodash.getPath(obj, val) == null || lodash.getPath(obj, val) == undefined || lodash.getPath(obj, val) == '') {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
    });
    return valid;
}
```

Usage:

```
leaveDetails = {
              "startDay": 1414998000000,
              "endDay": 1415084400000,
              "test": { "test1" : 1234 }

    };

    var validate;

    validate = invalidateRequest(leaveDetails, ['startDay', 'endDay', 'test.test1']);
```

it will return boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using **reduce** function (thanks [Brian K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2197509/bryan-k)).

Here we created a get/set to general proposes. The first function return the value in any level. The key is splited considering the separator. the function return the value refered from last index in the key's array

The second function will set the new value considering the last index of the splited key

the code:

```js
    function getObjectMultiLevelValue(_array,key,separator){
        key = key.split(separator || '.');
        var _value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_array));

        for(var ki in key){
                _value = _value[key[ki]];
        }
        return _value;
    }

    function setObjectMultiLevelValue(_array,key,value,forcemode,separator){
        key.split(separator || '.').reduce(function(prev, currKey, currIndex,keysArr) {
            var newObj = {};
            if(prev[currKey] && !forcemode){
                newObj = prev[currKey];
            }
            if(keysArr[keysArr.length-1] == currKey){
                newObj = value;
                prev[currKey] = newObj;
            }

            prev[currKey] = newObj;
            return newObj;
        }, _array);
        return _array;
    }

//testing the function
//creating an array
    var _someArray = {a:'a',b:'b',c:{c1:'c1',c2:{c21:'nothing here...'}}};
//a multilevel key to test
    var _key = 'a,a1,a21';
//any value
    var _value = 'new foo in a21 key forcing replace old path';

//here the new value will be inserted even if the path exists (forcemode=true). Using comma separator
    setObjectMultiLevelValue(_someArray,_key,_value,true,',');
    console.log('_someArray:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(_someArray));

//inserting another value in another key... using default separator
    _key = 'c.c2.c21';
    _value = 'new foo in c21 key';
    setObjectMultiLevelValue(_someArray,_key,_value);
    console.log('_someArray:');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(_someArray));

//recovering the saved value with different separators
    _key = 'a,a1,a21';
    console.log(getObjectMultiLevelValue(_someArray,_key,','));
    _key = 'c.c2.c21';
    console.log(getObjectMultiLevelValue(_someArray,_key));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let assume our object is

```js
const data = {
  //some other data
  userInfo: {},
};
```

First, define a new property of that object

```js
data.userInfo.vehicle = {};
```

then simply

```
data.userInfo.vehicle.vehicleType = state.userInfo.vehicleType;
```